# What should `jsx` be set to in a NextJS and Vite app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vitest

In order to avoid this error

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
 ❯ Module.Home [as default] src/app/page.tsx:2:3
      1| export default function Home() {
      2|   return <div>Home of Coach-Next</div>;
       |   ^
      3| }
```

I have to edit `tsconfig.json`to have

```
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
```

but when I run `npm run dev`, then it is changed to

```
    "jsx": "preserve",
```

and hence, my test fails.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to work around this, so both the test passes and the app can be run?

**home.test.ts**

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { test, expect } from "vitest";
import Home from "../app/page";

test("Home page", () => {
  render(Home());
  expect(screen.getByText("Home of Coach-Next")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.node.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Although there are ways of avoiding the import, to make more compatible with different build systems etc, I just do `import * as React from "react"`, it's really not that much effort.

Comment: It worked =) What I don't understand is why it worked when I did `npm run dev` but not `npm run test`. Why does one need the import and other doesn't?

Comment: I think it's just the way say webpack or whatever build system your using is configured.  I just remember it been a pain, you say would get the build system to work, but then Typescript would complain etc etc, in the end just thought it wasn't worth the hassle, and most units I'd need `useState`, `useEffect` etc anyway, so the auto import wouldn't do that.  But if you do wish to get this working and its using webpack, it's maybe https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/ that's not configured correctly in `test`.

Comment: What's in the `vite.config.ts` and `vitest.config.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

As @Keith pointed out in the comments, adding

```
import * as React from "react"
```

solved the problem.